# Why Should I use `this.name` instead of `name` in Person Constructor (and similar constructors)?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

Simple question. Why should I do this...

```
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sayHello = function(){
        console.log('Hello, my name is ' + this.name); // <-- 
    }
};
```

instead of...

```
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sayHello = function(){
        console.log('Hello, my name is ' + name); // <--
    }
};
```

I haven't found a situation that they behave differently.

Comment: You don't have to. It's the same in this example/context. Why do you think you have to?

Comment: `var fred = new Person("Fred"); fred.name = "Frederick"; fred.sayHello()`. See what both versions of your `Person` object do.

Comment: well in your case it does not matter since you update the class attribute beforehand anyway. However I consider it would be better to use this.name ( as in the class attribute) instead of the variable since the object is supposed to say hello and state its name ( as in objects name). Also that is a method defined on that class so it should use its own attributes.

Comment: Just a quick demonstration of why you might want to use `this`: https://jsbin.com/xofiraqatu/edit?js,console

Comment: @JeroenNoten: The examples on MDN and other examples I've seen have always shown the `this.name` version and I hadn't seen an explanation. I accidentally discovered the version sans `this` by being a good little coder and not copy/pasting. So I thought I'd ask what the difference is. Thanks for your comment. It is good to know that it's not necessarily required in the above context. Looks like more of a best practice to avoid situations like the one Ayan posted.

Comment: It's not "best practice" - the two usages are distinct. You _could_ want to pass something in and keep it "immutable" by not exposing it or you could pass a value in and expect it to change. But having both, like in your second example, is mostly nonsensical. If you have a field in your object the expectations that the field should matter. Moreover, there is the entire concept of `this` that you are either embracing or side-stepping. Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages and depend on the use case. As it happens _your_ implementation was flawed, not omitting `this`.

Comment: @vld 
_"...But having both, like in your second example, is mostly nonsensical..."_
-- I think you mean my _first_ example? 

_"...As it happens your implementation was flawed.."_.  
--Can you clarify if you mean my entire implementation or just the first example

Comment: No, I meant the _second_ example. It's the entire implementation of the second example. You pass in the value `name`, assign it to the object field called `name` but then you _don't_ use the field. That's neither here nor there. Example 1 is consistent, hence why `fred.name = "Frederick"` would change the name and the next invocation of `sayHello()` prints out the new name. With example 2's implementation `fred.name = "Frank"` wouldn't actually change the name reported - what @Ayan showed. So, in short, with example two, changing `name` doesn't change the name. As I said - flawed.

Comment: @Vld: Okay. I misunderstood what you meant by "having both" to mean "using `this` in both places is flawed" and "...implementation was flawed, [by] not omitting `this`" seemed to suggest that I _should_ omit `this`."

Comment: It's clear now what you were trying to communicate. Thank you, @Vld

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So if there is any function reseting the name, things wont get refelected if you aint using `this.name`. Check this example

```js
var Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sayHello = function() {
    console.log('Hello, my name is ' + name);
    console.log('Hello, my name is ' + this.name);// <--
  }
};
Person.prototype.resetName = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var me = new Person('A');
me.sayHello();
console.log('******');
me.resetName('Ayan');
me.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 1):

- this.name refers to the property "name" of the current object that "this" represents
- name is the parameter of the function.

As others already showed, the value of this.name could be changed by other instructions outside of the function you declare by changing the property on the object, while using name means you are closing over the parameter (which could in case of strings not be manipulated from outside the declared function, except maybe for freak cases)

Secondly, you assign this.name = name, but even that operation can "fail" (not do what might be intended, as in "change the value returned by this.name"). E.g. when you call the function with this set to an object that has a setter for the "name" property which is not trivial. That can happen even without any extra declared functions:

```js
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    console.log('Hello, my name is ' + this.name);
};

let obj = { set name(val) { }, get name() { return "unintended"; } };
Person.call(obj, "intended");
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter witch one you use.. `this.name` just assings the `name` variable into to your "class person" so you can use that variable in other functions inside your class.

Comment: In the second one `sayHello` closes over the initial `name`, the first doesn't. No?

Comment: Erm, it _does_ matter which one is used. Whether the effects are relevant to OP or not, is a different thing, though.